# PowerShell: Download specific files from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I have a question concerning downloading specific files from a s3 bucket.
Here are some parameters:
AWS.Tools.Common v4.0.6.0
PowerShell 7.0.2

I already have a script that downloads all files contained in a specific "folder" (there is no such thing, I know).
I want to alter it to download all files contained in a specific "subfolder"
The problem is, that I don't know how to access it.

The structure displayed in the AWS console looks like this:

- root/subfolder/subsubfolder2/theFolderIWant
- root/subfolder/subsubfolder4/theFolderIWant
- root/subfolder/subsubfolder7/theFolderIWant

and so on.

How can I iterate through all the subfolders to download the subfolders I need? The folders in question are always named in the same way.

Here is a snippit of the current code:

```
   $keyPrefixes = @("Key1/", "Key2/", "Key3/", "Key4/")
    foreach ($keyPrefix in $keyPrefixes) {

     $objects = Get-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -KeyPrefix $keyPrefix -AccessKey $accessKey -SecretKey $secretKey -Region $region
    
    
        foreach($object in $objects)
        {
            $localFileName = $object.Key -replace $keyPrefix, ''
            if ($localFileName -ne '')
            {
                $localFilePath = Join-Path $localPath $localFileName
          

      Copy-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -Key $object.Key -LocalFile $localFilePath -AccessKey $accessKey -SecretKey $secretKey -Region $region
        }
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your existing script and show what you've tried so far, that is the easiest way to get somebody to help you

Comment: Try and see it from our point of view. You ask for help on altering a script so it works for you, but you never show us the script, so we can never help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the code to the question